# c++ error when requesting member function

Tags: c++

I have a class like so

```
class action {
    int val;
    // some other members
public:
    action()        : val(0)   { } // default constructor initializes action type to 0
    action(int val) : val(val) { } 
    // some other member functions
    int getVal() { return val; }
};
```

and when used in a simple scenario

```
action obj1(), obj2(2);
cout << "Initial state : { " << obj1.getVal() << ", " << obj2.getVal() << " }\n";
```

I get a compilation error

```
error: request for member ‘getVal’ in ‘obj1’
```

What is going on here?

Comment: Look up "[most] vexing parse."

Comment: You should declare getVal as const: int getVal() const { return val; }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you are **not** declaring an `obj1` of type `action`

```
action obj1()
```

declares a function obj1 that takes no parameters and returns an action object. Prefer the c++11 brace initialization to call default constructor

```
action obj1{}
```

or just don't use those extra parentheses.

You can google for this issue, as **c++ most vexing parse**

Answer (score 3):

It's because the declaration

```
action obj1();
```

actually declares `obj1` to be a function which returns an `action` object. Unless you need to pass arguments to the constructor, drop the parentheses:

```
action obj1;
```

Answer (score 1):

replace `obj1()` with `obj1`. it will work

Answer (score 0):

In this statement

```
action obj1(), obj2(2);
```

you declared function

```
action obj1()
```

that has return type action and has no parameters and an object of type action

```
action obj2(2);
```

Change this statement to

```
action obj1, obj2(2);
```

The other way to avoid such an error is to write

```
action obj1 {}, obj2(2);
```

provided that your compiler supports the list initialization.

The problem is that there is an ambiguity between function declarations and object definitions with empty lists of arguments. C++ resolves the conflict for benefit of function declarations.

Answer (score 0):

To fix above mentioned error remove () in obj1 while declaring.